# Perform an action after user dismiss the app on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, background

I want to perform an action, ten seconds after the app goes to background and in condition that the user didn't back to the app during that time.

For doing so, I am using this code:

```
 -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

      UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier __block bgTask = 0;
      UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
      bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
           [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
           bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
      }];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
          [self checkSession];
      });
 }

  -(void)checkSession{
      sleep(10);
      if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateActive)  {
          NSLog(@"Do action after 10 seconds");
      }
      else{
         NSLog(@"Do nothing after 10 seconds");
      }
  }
```

The problem is that if the user terminate the app while it in background (By swipe it and dismiss it) , but before 10 seconds passed, the action will not be performed, and i'll see this log:

```
    <AppDelegate: 0x15557890> ending background task 5
```

Any idea how to perform the action in this case?

Comment: You can't. What is the action you're trying to take after the 10 seconds is up?

Comment: I am handling user sessions. I will send an event to the server. I want to end the session only if the user was not using the app more then 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` for the case that user kills the app before your action is performed

Comment: I already tried it. It not working. This method called in the moment the app goes to background, and that's it...

Comment: nope, applicationWillTerminate is called the moment when you terminate the app.Try to use timer instead of sleep

Comment: OK, you are right, applicationWillTerminate working :)

Comment: B.T.Y. timer is not working when the app on background

Comment: This is what I'm using for background timer and it is working just fine :
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(someAction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];